# Vue Cli 4 not copying index.html to output path

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-4

I need to copy the **index.html** in **public** to a specific folder defined in public path, but this is not working as I expect.

I also don't want the cli to include header and scripts references in the html file.

**My index html output** should contains only: `<div id='app'></div>` plus some specific html tags required by our CMS system.

For that I use:

```
    chainWebpack: config => {
        // disable splitting of JS files for dist folder
        config.optimization.delete('splitChunks')

        config.plugins
        .delete('html')
        .delete('prefetch')
        .delete('preload')
    }
```

But my **index.html** is not being copied to my output path.

If I remove `.delete('html')`, **index.html** will copy normally, but with headers and script references.

I had the same with Vue Cli 3 and this used to work. What am I missing?